# Where can I find maps for Baldur's Gate?

Tags: baldurs-gate

Years and years ago I put about 200 hours into Baldur's Gate and was getting near the end. Then that computer died and my new one was not able to run it due to problems with XP. I'm considering going back to the game now that patches are easily available, but the maps site I was using to find all the cool hidden areas has gone down. It was http://dspace.dial.pipex.com/m.james/ and it had great lablled maps, but it is long offline, and Wayback didn't archive the maps. I've looked around, but never run into anything as nice since: Does anyone have suggestions for maps that show the location of secrete/hard to find areas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [this](http://mikesrpgcenter.com/bgate/maps.html) is the best map for the job.

Comment: That looks very similar to the ones I had, but much lower resolution. It works well enough- Thank you! I'll accept if I don't get a better answer by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the very same site you suggested: http://web.archive.org/web/20021017051205/http://dspace.dial.pipex.com/m.james/

You should be able to find your old maps.

Comment: A few of the maps are there, but most were not archived, sadly.